# ADOQuery не возвращает результатов

Tags: sql, delphi, access, ado, odbc

Есть такой код:

```
Form3.Query.SQL.Clear;
Form3.Query.SQL.Add('SELECT Фамилия, Имя, Отчество');
Form3.Query.SQL.Add('FROM Студенты');
Form3.Query.SQL.Add('WHERE (((Студенты.[Код группы]) Like ''*'') AND ((Студенты.[Код])='+IntToStr(id)+'));');

Form3.Query.Open;

Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Запрос:');
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Form3.Query.SQL.Text);
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Результатов запроса: '+ IntToStr(Form3.Query.RecordCount));
```

Результат его выполнения:

> Запрос:
>   SELECT Фамилия, Имя, Отчество
>   FROM Студенты
>   WHERE (((Студенты.[Код группы]) Like '*') AND ((Студенты.[Код])=6));
>   Результатов запроса: 0

При том что выполняя этот же запрос в самом Access, я получаю результаты.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А если убрать всю строку с `WHERE` то результат такой же, 0 ?

Comment: Хмм, если выкинуть все условия отбора, то возвращается как и следует ожидать все 6 записей из таблицы. Стало быть ошибка в них.

Comment: А если вместо `*` попробовать `%`? По моему `LIKE` со звездочкой прокатывает только в самом Access'е.

Comment: Да, работает! Спасибо! Очень удивлен что это работает, я думал язык то соответствует стандарту, и везде един. А на деле вот как получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как в комментария подсказывает [Vasil Baymurzin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178618/vasil-baymurzin): LIKE с использованием условия * работает только в самом Access, используя ODBC такое не прокатит.